# Delete from database rows oldest by 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I have problem with my MySQL query.

I would like to query for delete rows oldest by 7 day from my table. This table has `day`, `month` and `year` in different rows.

This is my query:

```
DELETE FROM 
  `logowanie_dj` 
WHERE 
  `miesiac` 
IN (
  SELECT CONCAT(dzien,':', miesiac,':', rok) < 21:1:2014'
)
```

However `mysql_query()` is deleting all the rows.

Comment: I wonder why this SQL statement is even valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you mean year, month and day are in different *columns*?

Then this might work:

```
DELETE FROM `logowanie_dj` WHERE CAST(CONCAT(dzien,':',miesiac,':',rok) AS DATE) < CAST('21:1:2014' AS DATE)
```

It creates a date value in the form `dd:mm:yyyy` from the cells of the row and deletes it if it is before `21:1:2014`.

Please note that you obviously use some date format that is non-english. MySQL might have a problem with that, so that it could be you need to do this:

```
DELETE FROM `logowanie_dj` WHERE CAST(CONCAT(rok,'-',miesiac,'-',dzien) AS DATE) < CAST('2014-01-21' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

check the date and time format is correct or not. Try with this format **'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss'**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try casting the two strings into dates so it knows to do the comparison as dates.

> "For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE."

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_greater-than)

Answer (score 0):

*** Backup your database before trying this ***

```
DELETE FROM `logowanie_dj` 
WHERE ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(rok,'-',miesiac,'-',dzien))) > 604800
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code

```
    DELETE FROM 
  `logowanie_dj` 
WHERE 
  `miesiac` 
IN (
  SELECT CONCAT(dzien,':', miesiac,':', rok) < '2014:01:21 00:00:00'
)
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Without having tried I still doubt that this is even valid SQL (where's the `WHERE` clause before `<`?)